# What adhesive to use to glue back chips that came off of porcelain tiles?

Tags: tile, adhesive, chip

I have two very small chips that came off my large tiles, basically due to careless handling.
Although I did my best to handle them with care while I was trying to see if they fit, in two cases small chips came off the corners of my tiles and I can see that I could probably fix that y gluing back the chips and make the cracks almost invisible

Is there a recommended glue/adhesive for that ?

Update:Wall tiles, one chip in wet area 1.5ft above shower base, the other two are in a dry area one at around the same level the othe one is next to the floor, where the tile meets the floor tile

Comment: Floor or wall tile?  Wet area(shower) or dry?

Comment: I updated the post with the info you asked for

Comment: I've glued the handle of my beloved coffee mug using "super-glue", it stayed for another few years with daily uses.

Comment: For wall tiles almost any sticky glue should work, like silicone, contact, super-glue, etc.  It is very low weight and not abused area.

Comment: If there's a tight fit, f the chip fits nicely in its place and disappears into place without glue,  super glue should do nicely.

Comment: If the tile is black *just* use a sharpie.

Comment: That's my wife's favorite solution, @Mazura, she has Sharpies in a multitude of colors...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"Trying to see if they fit" implies "not installed yet" implies get two more tiles, or re-purpose these ones to locations where the chipped part will be trimmed off.

That's the right fix.

The other fix is cyanoanacrylate, AKA superglue, but it's simply not the same as an undamaged tile, and if the tile is not installed yet, it's a foolish way to save a few bucks on replacement tiles.

Comment: They are installed now.  The were damaged duri g the dry fit ...one is at the bottom of the walll under the floating vanity caninet. The other one is going to be behind the same cabinet in the corner. So none of these will be really visible and that is why I installed them like that. The last one is the smalest o e and barely visible...I thing this very very small chip came off when I twated to see if that corner of the time was flat with the above tiles....all in all not a big deal but I think I can use Horrila glue or maybe even PL

Comment: "chip came off when I twated" that's... awkward, @MiniMe. Maybe proof read to see what autocowreck has done to your post before hitting "send"? ;)

Comment: Also, between this answer and several comments, the suggestion is CA/super glue, yet you're going to use "Horrila glue" or "maybe even PL"? Why bother asking the question if you're going to ignore the advice?

Comment: sorry for the typos I was typing while installing the last tiles, I was doing it using my smart phone and the thiset was getting dry so no time to check the spelling

Comment: If you meant to type Gorrila Glue, then that is a very bad choice for this situation. Gorilla Glue has a tendency to expand when it sets. Super glue  or its' gel version will not expand while setting up.